# Cannot copy databases in PHPMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I try to copy a database within PHPMyAdmin and I get the error - cannot copy database 'does not exist'.

If I then hit 'go' again, error message says 'cannot copy databse already exists'.

I have previously also tried 'creating database' and then trying to copy. The error message is as the second instance. Cannot copy, as db already exists.

This has only started happening recently (Mid July 2013). But means I cannot copy outwith 'export/import'.

Anyone with any ideas. I'm using PHPMyAdmin from within Cpanel on a shared webserver.

Comment: Some screenshots and a description of your procedure would help.   Does the destination database already exist?

Comment: @DavidGrayson: this is also happening to me, at first it says that database does not exist, then in second attempt it says it exists and therefore it can not be copied.

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version?